# Profile git commands time

Tags: macos, git, mercurial, benchmarking, osx-mountain-lion

Recently, while customising my prompt, I tried to benchmark (to no avail) some git commands, in order to find the fastest way to, for example, get the HEAD branch name.

Now, while adding support for Mercurial, I noticed there is a `--profile` option that prints the time and the low-level operations a Mercurial commands performs while at it.

Do you know something like that for git? And if there isn’t, where should I request it?

Platform is MacOs X 10.8.2.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to mention it. I’m on OS X 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What platform are you using? In case of Linux or Mac OS X, you can always use `time` command. For example:

```
time git status
```

Comment: OS X 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion), and I already coded a benchmarking shell script (with $before and $after variables holding `date %s%N`), but I don’t get reliable results. It seems the results or something is cached, because I get only similar results after two tries of the same command: `bench git symbolic-ref --short 2>/dev/null`, for example. Oh, and I’m using GNU date tools thanks to Homebrew.

Comment: @AndrésBotero You don't really need a benchmarking script, IMO. If `time` will do the trick, use it. Granted, "cold" runs will still be slower than the subsequent ones, so in order to get a meaningful result you should probably start measuring from the second one onwards.

Comment: I see examples getting 0.000, but I only get 0.00, even with GNU time. Anything I can do? I don’t remember now, but I think that’s why I made the script with nanoseconds.

Comment: It seems the bash and zsh builtin time command is a reliable source. I might as well use them (again) just to use their builtin command.

Comment: @AndrésBotero Nano seconds precision are for fine granularity profiling like individual functions. In case of git commands executions, they access the spinning disk or network, and are subjected to OS scheduling, which can introduce so many milliseconds or even seconds level random latencies that almost makes nanoseconds precision profiling a moot.

Comment: Well, in this case, nanoseconds are better than simply getting zeroes. In any case, I think I’m going to request that profiling feature of git. It might not be for everybody, but it can really help in use cases like mine.